# Sqoop query is creating Multiple Sessions One inactive and One Active

Tags: oracle, sqoop

When I am executing SQOOP Query, its creating multiple sessions in Oracle.

I want to have only ONE ACTIVE SESSION per sqoop query.

The SQOOP Query is:

```
sqoop import - Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://a/b/pwd.password.jceks 
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager 
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//21.12.12.21:2500/W1P923 
--username USERNAME 
--password-alias alias-USER 
--query 
       "SELECT CONCAT(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'.000000') 
        as HDFS_LOAD_DTTM, CONCAT(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'.000000') 
        as HDFS_UPDATE_DTTM, (nvl(SUM(SCHEME_ROUND),0)-nvl(SUM(NUM_OF_TO),0)) 
        AS USED_BD, 'A' as INDICATOR from RACKER PARTITION(RACKER_PR121) 
        WHERE \$CONDITIONS GROUP SCHEME_ROUND" 
--escaped-by \\\\ --null-string '' --null-non-string '' 
--direct --fields-terminated-by '|' -m 1 
--target-dir /dev/racker_month/partDate=RACKER_PR121 &
```

Answer (score 1):

There will be at least 2 sessions for your sqoop script.

- One for getting the metadata for your query to generate java class to perform the import. Once the java class is generated, sqoop will create jar file and use the jar for the import.
- As you have number of mappers as 1, it will create another session to perform the import.

It is the behavior of Oracle that it is showing the first session to be inactive. It will be closed after some time.

What ever you are seeing is expected behavior. You can see the details of the query by joining v$session and v$sql to get the details of queries sqoop is running in those sessions.